# MAUI: Change telerik button text based on property value

Tags: c#, telerik, maui

I am quite new to MAUI, in the learning phase of it

I have a telerik button in a popup, like this

```
<telerik:RadButton Text="Add" CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=AddNewNote}}" Command="{Binding OkCommand}"></telerik:RadButton>
```

And I have a property `Name` in my view model

What I want is that while opening the popup if the `Name` is empty then the button text should say `Add` else `Update`

Could somebody help me how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you familiar with converters? If so, you can use this here. You can also use triggers. Let me know if you want me to post more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if the `Name` is empty then the button text should say `Add` else `Update`

You can achieve it by the following code:

Page.xaml:

```xml
...
<Entry Text="{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<Button Text="{Binding BtnText}" Command="{Binding OkCommand}"/>
...
```

Page.xaml.cs:

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new VM();
}
```

ViewModel:

```cs
public class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    private string btnText;
    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set
        {
            if (name != value)
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public string BtnText
    {
        get => btnText;
        set
        {
            if (btnText != value)
            {
                btnText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public Command OkCommand { get; }
    public VM()
    {
        OkCommand = new Command(OnOk, IsNull);
        PropertyChanged += (_, __) => OkCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
    }
    private bool IsNull()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name))
        {
            BtnText = "Update";
            return true;
        }
        BtnText = "Add";
        return true;
    }

    private void OnOk()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ss");
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "") =>
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
}
```

Here is the [effect](https://imgur.com/a/4GJTgTw), and the button text can change dynamically(Add/Update) based on whether Name is empty or not.